# How do I check out files with special characters in the file name (e.g. ?) on Windows in Git while keeping the original name in the repo?

Tags: windows, git

I have a bunch of files in a Git repo which works okay on macOS and Linux, but will fail on Windows because the file name contains `?`

I was wondering how do I configure Git only on my local Windows machine so that I can check it out and have it auto convert the file to something Windows will allow and push it back preserving the file name?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: You can't do it *automatically*. It is possible to work with these commits, but it requires a lot of painstaking hand-holding of Git. You could conceivably write your own program to deal with these specific file names, hence automating your particular case, though.

Comment: What you will need to do is ignore the failure of a `git checkout` and carefully manipulate the "tricky" file using `git ls-files` and `git update-index` to extract the blob hash ID, write a file with some other name, and then update the index under the original name using the working tree copy that's under the other name.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux.  It has a fully POSIX-compatible file system and is fully capable of storing arbitrary byte values (with the normal exceptions).

It is almost certainly not going to be possible to use Git for Windows on a native Windows file system, although if you happened to format an external hard disk as UDF (which, I believe, requires the full disk, not just a partition, to be formatted that way on Windows), then you could probably check it out there.  UDF is at least capable of handling these characters on Unix.